# C / C++ Library for HTTPS Client with Basic Authentication

Tags: c++, c, linux, https, basic-authentication

Do you recommend any good library or examples online for implementing an HTTPS client that can connect to a website using basic authentication? This is meant to run in linux servers.

Any pointers help.

**Update:** Question about the unanimous libcurl - does it come bundled by default in major distributions like Debian, Ubuntu, Gentoo, Slackware, RedHat and Arch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) supports both HTTPS and HTTP Basic Authentication.  There's plenty of example code online.

All of the distributions you mention have libcurl packaged.  It is not absolutely certain to be installed, but it is *very* common.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it's supported by the OSes I mention on my update?

Comment: I meant distribution, sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/)

> A free and easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library, supporting FTP, FTPS, HTTP, HTTPS, SCP, SFTP, TFTP, TELNET, DICT, FILE, LDAP and LDAPS. libcurl supports HTTPS certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, kerberos, HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication, file transfer resume, http proxy tunneling and more.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) and can recommend it.